# Lookup-able models

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm currently working on a project using `MongoDB` as it's database and I got some issues on how to solve the problem of having a model containing some ids to foreign documents and looking them up without needing to fall back to `BsonDocument`.

Originally I had this (stripped down) model class:

```
public class TestSession
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("taskId")]
    public ObjectId? TaskId { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes I need the concrete `TaskConfiguration` referenced by `TaskId`.
In this case I use a `$lookup` to resolve it.

First I introduced a new member to hold the concrete `TaskConfiguration` instance changing my model class to:

```
public class TestSession
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("taskId")]
    public ObjectId? TaskId { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public TaskConfiguration Task { get; set; }
}
```

Then I realized that the aggregation was unable to deserialize the looked-up and unwound `Task` value, I guess because of `BsonIgnore`.
I could not find any options to override this and I couldn't come up with any other solution to this.

Finally I decided to split the model class into the initial one containing exactly the database representation of the document and a derived class containing the resolved `Task` member without the `BsonIgnore` attribute in order for it to be deserializable.

The resulting classes look like this:

```
public class TestSessionModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("taskId")]
    public ObjectId? TaskId { get; set; }
}

public class TestSession : TestSessionModel
{
    [BsonElement("task")]
    public TaskConfiguration Task { get; set; }
}
```

Although this approach seems to work I now have to split up all similiar classes which not only creates a lot of classes potentially but also could potentially confuse the reader what class to use.
Additionally one has to be careful to not store the derived classes into the database.

My question now is if my current approach is actually the way to go in this case or if there are better/safer alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the `BsonIgnore` approach but you need to project the final result like this:

```cs
var res = collection.AsQueryable()
                    .Where(t => t.Id == session.Id)
                    .Join(
                        foreignColl.AsQueryable(), // foreign collection
                        s => s.TaskId,             // local field
                        c => c.Id,                 // foreign field
                        (s, c) => new TestSession  // projection
                        {
                            Id = s.Id,
                            Name = s.Name,
                            TaskId = s.TaskId,
                            Task = c
                        })
                    .Single();
```

here's the full program i used for testing:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class TestSession : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string TaskID { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public TaskConfiguration Task { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskConfiguration : Entity
    {
        public int NumOfIterations { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            var task = new TaskConfiguration { NumOfIterations = 10 };
            task.Save();

            var session = new TestSession { Name = "This is a test session", TaskID = task.ID };
            session.Save();

            var res = DB.Queryable<TestSession>()
                        .Where(t => t.ID == session.ID)
                        .Join(
                            DB.Queryable<TaskConfiguration>(),
                            s => s.TaskID,
                            c => c.ID,
                            (s, c) => new TestSession
                            {
                                ID = s.ID,
                                Name = s.Name,
                                TaskID = s.TaskID,
                                Task = c
                            })
                        .Single();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this would be another solution but this doesn't play well if the model classes are way bigger than the example. The original model class contains about 11 properties excluding the ones I would use for resolved instances. Maybe I could put the projection code somewhere else for reuse but an automatic mapping solution would still be far better as there would be no additional mapping code to maintain/forget about ;) Thanks though for you solution.

Comment: @TorbenJ agreed. it's less than ideal. how about projecting to an anonymous type like so: `(s, c) => new 
                            {
                                Session = s,
                                Task = c
                            })`